# How to adjust legend in a row in R?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have one plot and i need to adjust legends in a row. How can i do it?

```
plot(x,y)
legend(c("x","y"))
```

I need legend should be in one line

```
    ----- x                 --------- y
```

Regards

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of data you are using? And maybe one link to a graph that looks like the one you are trying to create. Tks.

Answer (score 4):

You want to set `horiz=TRUE` in `legend`. Here's a comparison of the default behavior (`horiz=FALSE`) to `horiz=TRUE`.

[image]

This plot is based on [the second example from the `legend` documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html):

```
layout(matrix(1:2,nrow=1))
# `horiz=FALSE` (default behavior)
plot(x, sin(x), type = "l", ylim = c(-1.2, 1.8), col = 3, lty = 2, main="horiz=FALSE (Default)")
points(x, cos(x), pch = 3, col = 4)
lines(x, tan(x), type = "b", lty = 1, pch = 4, col = 6)
legend(-1, 1.9, c("sin", "cos", "tan"), col = c(3, 4, 6),
       text.col = "green4", lty = c(2, -1, 1), pch = c(NA, 3, 4),
       merge = TRUE, bg = "gray90")
# `horiz=TRUE`
plot(x, sin(x), type = "l", ylim = c(-1.2, 1.8), col = 3, lty = 2, main="horiz=TRUE")
points(x, cos(x), pch = 3, col = 4)
lines(x, tan(x), type = "b", lty = 1, pch = 4, col = 6)
legend(-1, 1.9, c("sin", "cos", "tan"), col = c(3, 4, 6),
       text.col = "green4", lty = c(2, -1, 1), pch = c(NA, 3, 4),
       merge = TRUE, bg = "gray90", horiz=TRUE)
```